# How to record video for a HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Is there a way to record an HTML element? I am aware that there is the `.captureStream()` for `canvas` elements. Is there anything similar to that for HTML elements? Is there an alternate way where I can record part of the website?

Comment: What do you mean by record a html element?

Comment: Similar to `captureStream`, get a MediaSteam back, so I can do something with it.

Comment: Record from a camera?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no HTML element for recording an part of the website as far as I know. You may need to mess up with JavaScript, I guess.

Comment: Any ideas on how would I got about recording something?